# Managing public SSH keys for access to an application running as non-root user

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

We have a server application that is running as several independent instances on individual machines. We currently have telnet access to them (from inside the local network only but they're still fairly open) and are trying to replace it with an embedded SSH server. We have added SSH access using Apache sshd but are struggling to come up with a secure/practical method for managing the keys.

- The servers are all running as the same (non-root) user with access to a shared filesystem (as well as their own local drive).
- There are a number of people with admin rights for the server application but not for the main networking infrastructure (no root access but su access to the user the servers are running as)

  - these people should have SSH access to all the servers
- Each server has people without admin rights who should be able to access that server with SSH but not the other ones.
- Every user should have their own key

Is there a standard way of dealing with SSH access to an application that doesn't have root privileges?

The current line of thinking is to have a common directory with the server admin keys in and subdirectories for the individual server but finding the right level of permissions to prevent write access but prevent overwriting other people's keys is proving challenging. If possible we'd prefer not to have to go via sysadmins to add/remove as root.

Comment: have you considered using OpenSSH (typically already installed on the OS)? With openssh, the user's public key is appended to their `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (in their home directory). User's can manage their `authorized_keys` file themselves. OpenSSH client comes with a command `ssh-copy-id` which simplifies handling `authorized_keys`.

Comment: How would that work for embedding in an application? As users are connecting to a process that is running as a different user, the server wouldn't be able to access users' authorized_keys files.

Comment: If embedding and running the SSH server as non-root user are requirements, OpenSSH may not be a good fit.

Comment: If you're looking to implement SSH in an application, this is an application development question, suitable for Stack Overflow, and not a system management question.  How you manage keys will be largely dependent on what facilities are provided by your chosen sshd library.

Comment: @womble, I already have the ssh server embedded in the application. It can read public keys from anywhere it's told to; that bit's not the problem. I'm looking to find a solution to managing where the keys are stored in a secure but convenient way.

Comment: Well, that's very different from what you're asking.  To properly answer a security-related question you need to know your threat model, for starters.